# HighStock how to set default invisible for all series

Tags: highcharts

I want to set invisible for all series. Where and how can i set this option please. I found that posibility only in HighChart. Could you help me please?

I mean that legend will be disable and you can choose which series you want to display, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use visible parameter `visible:false` http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.visible

http://jsfiddle.net/hNXXg/

or

http://jsfiddle.net/dusPn/

Comment: The `visible` parameter is not available in HighCharts, only in HighStock. I'm assuming since this post was tagged as highstock, that should be OK, but it is something to be aware of. If you are only using HighCharts, see the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468534/disable-series-through-configuration-in-highcharts

Comment: Sure it is: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.visible  I use it all the time in Highcharts.